# Is it possible to plot real-time RF signal spectrum via Python

Tags: deep-learning, signal-processing, detection

I'm wondering if it is possible to make spectrum analyzer via python using PlutoSDR.

have anybody tried it before?

or I'd like to ask if there's any different way to get real-time RFsignal to detect a drone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly0sk.png)

adi library -> I'm not sure if it really works.. I could only get low frequency.

```
import numpy as np
import adi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

sample_rate = 1e6  # Hz
center_freq = 915e6  # Hz
num_samps = 100000  # number of samples per call to rx()

sdr = adi.Pluto("ip:192.168.2.1")
sdr.sample_rate = int(sample_rate)

# Config Rx
sdr.rx_lo = int(center_freq)
sdr.rx_rf_bandwidth = int(sample_rate)
sdr.rx_buffer_size = num_samps
sdr.gain_control_mode_chan0 = 'manual'
sdr.rx_hardwaregain_chan0 = 0.0

# Clear buffer just to be safe
for i in range(0, 10):
    raw_data = sdr.rx()

# Create a figure and axis for the frequency domain plot
fig, ax_freq_time = plt.subplots()

# Initialize the lines that will be updated in the animation
line_freq, = ax_freq_time.plot([], [])

# Set labels and legend
ax_freq_time.set_xlabel("Frequency [MHz]")
ax_freq_time.set_ylabel("Amplitude")


# Set axis limits
ax_freq_time.set_xlim(-sample_rate / 2e6, sample_rate / 2e6)
ax_freq_time.set_ylim(0, 2000)  # Adjust the y-axis limit based on your data

# Initialize the data for the frequency domain plot
freq_data = np.zeros(num_samps)

# Update function for the animation
def update(frame):
    global freq_data
    # Receive samples
    rx_samples = sdr.rx()

    # Calculate power spectral density (frequency domain version of signal)
    psd = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(rx_samples))) ** 2
    psd_dB = 10 * np.log10(psd)
    freq_data = psd_dB

    # Calculate time domain from frequency domain data
    time_domain = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(psd))
    time_domain = np.abs(time_domain)

    # Update frequency domain plot
    f = np.linspace(-sample_rate / 2, sample_rate / 2, len(psd_dB))
    line_freq.set_data(f / 1e6, time_domain)

    return line_freq,

# Create the animation
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=10, blit=True)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```